CallerArgumentExpression with implicit casting
I have the following structure:
public sealed class KeyValue(object value, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string keyName = null)
{
    public string Key { get; set; } = keyName;
    public object Value { get; set; } = value;

    public static implicit operator KeyValue(string value) => new KeyValue(value);
}

I want to be able to implicit cast a string and take its name as a key example:
string ThisIsMyName = "Test";
KeyValue pair = ThisIsMyName;

Console.WriteLine(pair.Key) //should print ThisIsMyName
Console.WriteLine(pair.Value) // should print Test

Currently the following is valid (but I would like to remove the brackets and the new keyword):
string ThisIsMyName = "Test";
KeyValue pair = new(ThisIsMyName);

Console.WriteLine(pair.Key) //prints ThisIsMyName
Console.WriteLine(pair.Value) //prints Test

And in the ideal scenario i would have something like the following:
Task HandleFailureAsync(params KeyValue[] parameters)
----------
string test1 = "t1";
string test2 = "t2";
KeyValue testKey1 = test1;
KeyValue testKey2 = test2;
HandleFailureAsync(testKey1, testKey2);
//instead of 
HandleFailureAsync(new(test1), new(test2));

Does anybody have any good ideas/solutions?

I can't think of any way to do this. You "need" to have the CallerArgumentExpression me a parameter to your implicit operator, but of course there's no way to do that

First of all, are you sure that the "prints ThisIsMyName" is correct? It certainly doesn't seem so here

@DavidG it seems that the first snippet is what OP wants, not actual behavior (which is in second one).

@DavidG this is what I want to achive, I will edit the comment to should print

Even given that, I think you are abusing what CallerArgumentExpression was intended for. even the docs state it is used to "Allow developers to capture the expressions passed to a method, to enable better error messages in diagnostic/testing APIs and reduce keystrokes". i.e. it is a diagnostic feature, not a thing you should be using to capture data.

I would argue that less code is not always better and this is potentially a quite brittle approach. I would recommend to be explicit here and just pass the keyName as a parameter and remove the implicit conversion.
